# Hyperlink with image in one QTableView cell

Tags: qt, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel, qitemdelegate

I have a QTableView with custom model and delegate. Task is to create cell which will contain image and hyperlink. By clicking on image user will copy hyperlink to clipboard, and by clicking of hyperlink user should open link in browser.

Is it a possible task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure it is possible.

One of the way to solve this is to use call `setIndexWidget()` of view where you bypass `QLabel` with image or hyperlink or both using html (rtf).

Another way is to have own subclassed `QItemDelegate` in which you can reimplement `createEditor()` and set persistent editor with `openPersistenEditor()`.